# AKS nodepool scaleset fault domains count is always 1

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-vm-scale-set

When you create just the vm scaleset in azure as a separate resource, you get 5 fault domains (5 - is a default fault domains count in a regular scaleset according to the microsoft documentation):
[image]

But when the scaleset is a part of AKS deployment (nodepool scaleset) fault domains count is alway 1 and there is no way to change it:

[image]

Why is it so? Did not find any explanation on this part.

Answer (score 0):

There is no doc to elaborate on this problem, at least I don't find it. But with my searching, I find that there is a property `platformFaultDomainCount` in the VMSS and when you create the VMSS only, you can set this property as you want, for example, 5. Then the VMSS has 5 fault domain count.

But for AKS, you only can configure the agent pool with `VirtualMachineScaleSets` with the property `platformFaultDomainCount`. And you also can't configure the VMSS. When all infrastructure resources finish creating, you then find the VMSS with the fault domain count 1. So I think it's the default value of the AKS when you select the `VirtualMachineScaleSets` as the agent pool and you can't change.